# GPS bounding box around 2 points

Tags: gps, box, bounding

I have 2 GPS locations with a latitude and a longitude.

I want to create a bounding box, which incorporates both these points, plus some number of kilometers of padding on either side (for example, a 10km bounding box which includes both point X and point Y).

I have seen implementations for bounding boxes around 1 singular GPS location, but I have not seen any implementations which incorporate 2 GPS locations.

Can somebody help with an implementation, or the name of a solution?

Comment: you should be able to get two (using one of your found implementations) and then calculate the bounding box of these two yourself?

Comment: The problem is, I dont know how to use 2 points to solve this problem. For example, http://JanMatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates works for 1 point, but when there are 2 points, I dont know how to extrapolate from this.